# How to check if a number is bigger than another number, by a certain amount?

Tags: javascript

how would I go about producing the following if statement?

```
var a = 50;
var b = 10;

if(a > b by 20){
    console.log("a is too big");
}
```

Comment: How about `a + 20 > b`?

Comment: I`m curious how did you figure out how to use the comparison operator, but not the addition :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(a - b > 20) {
  console.log('You didnt try much it seems')

}
```

Comment: I know you bastards are up voting for the witty console.log. I love you too <3

Comment: I know, happens. Just teasing

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer a question and participate to SO! Do note however that this question is unlikely to help future visitors because it was simply a typo issue. As such, even your answer is not useful. In the future please consider _whether your answer is useful not only to the asker, but also to future visitors_. You'd rather flag the question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
if (a > (b + 20)) {
  console.log("a is too big");
}
```

Comment: This answer is marginally more expressive.